# More then one audio session per single application instance

Tags: c++, windows, ms-media-foundation, audiosession, wasapi

Does WASAPI or Media Foundation allow creating several audio sessions for single process?

Answer (score 1):

[Managing the Audio Session (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374921%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Especially:

> ... Typically, an application maintains a single audio session, **although applications can create more than one session.** ...

Comment: Thank you for response! Can you give me more information, example or something else?

Answer (score 1):

When calling `IMMDevice::Activate` you have an option to provide parameters that point to a specific session you need. Having it `NULL` you would be attached to default session.

> guidAudioSession
>
> [Session GUID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370826%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This member is a GUID value that identifies the audio session that the stream belongs to. If the GUID identifies a
>   session that has been previously opened, the method adds the stream to
>   that session. If the GUID does not identify an existing session, the
>   method opens a new session and adds the stream to that session. The
>   stream remains a member of the same session for its lifetime.